# jwplayer 6 seeking on element in playlist doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

We're using an external scrubber (a UI element that is not the default seek bar) for seeking (via jquery ui draggable) and it is not updating the jwplayer when it should be.

### Synopsis of our code:

```
$('#scrubber').draggable({

    // ...

    stop: function (event, ui) {

        $('#scrubber').draggable('enable');

        var intSecFromEnd,
            intSeek,
            intTotalTime = 0,
            intScrubPosition = ui.position.left,
            intScrubTime = intScrubPosition;

        // Find which video in the playlist to use
        $.each(playlist, function (i, obj) {

            intTotalTime += parseInt(obj.duration);

            if (intTotalTime > (intScrubTime)) {

                intSecFromEnd = intTotalTime - parseInt(intScrubTime);
                intSeek = Math.floor((parseInt(obj.duration) - intSecFromEnd));

                jwplayer('videoPlayer').load(playlist);
                jwplayer('videoPlayer').playlistItem(i);
                jwplayer('videoPlayer').seek(intSeek);
                jwplayer('videoPlayer').pause();


                /*
                    Play the video for 1 second to refresh the video player, so it is correctly displaying the current point in the video
                    Does not work either
                */
                // setTimeout(function () {
                //     jwplayer('videoPlayer').pause();
                // }, 1000);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You'll notice the key bit:

```
jwplayer('videoPlayer').load(playlist);
jwplayer('videoPlayer').playlistItem(i);
jwplayer('videoPlayer').seek(intSeek);
jwplayer('videoPlayer').pause();
```

When i put this into the console directly with an integer value where `intSeek` is it works exactly as it should, so I'm puzzled where the disconnect might be.

### variation (that only works one one item in the playlist)

This works on the first member of the playlist only because the seek() function is defaulted to element `0` in the playlist.

```
jwplayer('videoPlayer').load(playlist);
jwplayer('videoPlayer').seek(intSeek);
jwplayer('videoPlayer').pause();
```

Naturally, it would stand to reason that `jwplayer('videoPlayer').playlistItem(i)` would retrieve the item at the index we want and, according to the docs, should:

> Start playback of the playlist item at the specified index.

but, as this is effectively what is in the first example, it doesn't work.

### Notes

- When triggering the `.seek()` method externally from the player, the `onSeek()` method never gets fired by the jwplayer.
- putting in the following, the jwplayer `onReady` event never gets fired. `jwplayer(strVideo).playlistItem(i).onReady({ console.log('ready'); });`

Comment: .. I'm lost how that even works in the first place; that is invalid syntax for accessing methods, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Which lines are you referring to?

Comment: Every single time you access without a dot.  That is not valid js syntax.

Comment: Ahh, alright then, lol

Comment: Can you put up a test page to where you are running this?

Comment: Figured it out this morning! I was simply neglecting to re-initialize the player when new elements were being added to the playlist array. I feel very very silly. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

we're trying onPlaylistItem(index).seek(seconds) but this doesn't works. 
This work only on active playlistitem and -of course- only about first file.

We're trying to use a pre-loaded playlist with seek button for every item of playlist. 
We use a playlist with more files and the user can go to a specific file and second clicking a button that call:

```
jwplayer().onPlaylistItem(<index_file>).seek(seconds);
```

This jump to the seconds but not to the correct playlist item.

With a previuos test using "playListItem" player jump to the correct file but start from beginning and not seek to seconds. (but work only in html5 mode and not with flash).

Now we've tested  this code

```
<a onclick='var only_once =false;jwplayer().playlistItem(1);jwplayer().onPlay(function () {  
if (only_once == false) {
        only_once = true;
          jwplayer().seek(60);
    }
});' class="btn">HLS play 2nd file at 1 min</a>
```

but this solution works only in Flash mode and not in html 5 mode player!